# I transferred my Laravel project to hosting, but I get a 403 not found error

Tags: laravel

I transferred my Laravel project to hosting, but I get a 403 not found error. What do you think is the reason?

.htcaccess file

```
           <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  Options +FollowSymLinks



    </IfModule>
```

Comment: clear your cache `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work :(

Comment: "_I get a 403 not found error_" 403 is a "Forbidden" status though

Comment: is your .htaccess and index file in the same folder?

Comment: I'm getting this error now Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'efsaneki_kitchen'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)